# Adding Iron-Router package to Meteor 0.6.4.1 in Windows 7

Tags: javascript, windows, meteor, iron-router

I'm running Meteor on my Win7.  Since Meteorite isn't supported on Windows yet, I'm following the instructions mentioned in http://goo.gl/BWauOk.  I configured my settings to bypass the proxy and I'm able to git clone the packages and dependencies for iron-router.  So, I don't think I have an issue with my proxy settings.  However, I get the following error when I try to launch meteor from my project:

```
$ meteor
[[[[[ c:\temp\projects\testapp ]]]]]

iron-router: updating npm dependencies -- connect...
No dependency info in bundle. Filesystem monitoring disabled.
=> Errors prevented startup:
Exception while bundling application:
Error: Can't install npm dependencies. Check your internet connection and try ag
ain.
    at Object._.extend._ensureConnected (c:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\tools\met
eor_npm.js:375:13)
    at Object._.extend._installNpmModule (c:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\tools\me
teor_npm.js:344:10)
    at _.extend._createFreshNpmDirectory (c:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\tools\me
teor_npm.js:198:12)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (c:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\lib\node_modules
\underscore\underscore.js:86:24)
    at Object._.extend._createFreshNpmDirectory (c:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\t
ools\meteor_npm.js:197:7)
    at Object._.extend.updateDependencies (c:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\tools\m
eteor_npm.js:85:14)
    at _.extend.installNpmDependencies (c:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\tools\pack
ages.js:317:17)
    at _.extend._maybeUpdateNpmDependencies (c:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\tools
\bundler.js:441:13)
    at _.extend.use (c:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\tools\bundler.js:480:10)
    at self.api.use (c:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\tools\bundler.js:133:21)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (c:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\lib\node_modules
\underscore\underscore.js:78:11)
    at Object.self.api.use (c:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\tools\bundler.js:129:9
)
    at null.on_use_handler (c:\temp\projects\testapp\packages\blaze-la
yout\package.js:6:7)
    at _.extend.use (c:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\tools\bundler.js:483:11)
    at self.api.use (c:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\tools\bundler.js:133:21)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (c:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\lib\node_modules
\underscore\underscore.js:78:11)
    at Object.self.api.use (c:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\tools\bundler.js:129:9
)
    at _.extend.init_from_app_dir [as on_use_handler] (c:\Program Files (x86)\Me
teor\tools\packages.js:238:11)
    at _.extend.use (c:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\tools\bundler.js:483:11)
    at Object.exports.bundle (c:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\tools\bundler.js:897
:12)
    at c:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\tools\run.js:698:26
    at exports.inFiber (c:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\tools\fiber-helpers.js:24:
12)

Please fix the problem and restart.
```

What should I doing to run my meteor app from Windows 7?

Comment: Are you using Meteor 0.9? As of 0.9 you no longer need Meteorite to add third-party packages, you can use `meteor add iron:router`. Don’t know that this will fix your issue, but it’s worth a try.

Comment: How can I find out what version of meteor I have?  I installed the latest .exe bootstrapper from win.meteor.com.   is that version 0.9?  Btw, I thought iron-router doesn't work with meteor 0.9, at least that's what I gather from atmosphere.

Comment: You can find out the version by running `meteor --version`. No the windows port of 0.9.x is not released yet. iron:router has been updated to work with the 0.9.x versions of meteor.

Comment: It came back with "Unreleased (running from a checkout).  I went to Add/Remove programs and found the version is 0.6.4.1.  Clearly, I'm below the mark.  How do I get this to work on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

> [Iron Router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router) works with Meteor 0.8.0 and above. To use an earlier version, use a version of IR less than 0.7.0.

You have specified the version in your smart.json?

Comment: I have version 0.6.1 in my iron-router\smart.json.
{
  "name": "router",
  "description": "A Reactive Router for multipage apps",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router",
  "author": "Tom Coleman <tom@thesnail.org>",
  "version": "0.6.1",
  "git": "https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router.git",
  "packages": {
    "page-js-ie-support": {},
    "HTML5-History-API": {}
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

Currently only a ancient build of Meteor for windows exists. A lot of things have changed/improved since the version of the current windows port(0.6).

Official windows support is [under consideration](https://trello.com/b/hjBDflxp/meteor-roadmap) for version 1.1 so it will be a while till you'll get proper windows support.

So best thing to do for the time being is to run a linux vm with your Meteor application. Luckily this is something that is very easy to do with vagrant.

1. Run: `git clone https://github.com/gfk-ba/meteor-dev-vm.git`
2. Put your application in the app directory.
3. Make sure you have cygwin and vagrant installed. (cygwin comes with git for windows so you should have that already)

Then run:

```
cd meteor-dev-vm/tools
./setup.sh
./run.sh
```

Now you have a linux development vm with the latest versions of meteor and meteorite. You can use `vagrant ssh` to connect to it. After which you can easily use meteorite or meteor's new packaging system.

Comment: I tried to git clone that command
'git clone git@github.com:gfk-ba/meteor-dev-vm.git'
and I get the following error:
**ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Bad file number
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.**

Comment: @inquisitive_one Then you probaply dont have a github account. I updated my answer

Comment: After `./setup.sh`, I get the following:  `meteor-dev-vm/.git
meteor-dev-vm/.git
Downloading or copying the box...
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error--)
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

Failed connect to dl.dropboxusercontent.com:443; No error`.  Now what do I do?